# Janus WebRTC installation issue

Tags: installation, makefile, webrtc, janus-gateway

I am installing Janus WebRTC Gateway in a Ubuntu  Machine (14.04 64 bit). I followed the instructions as in the following link:

However, I get the following error when trying to execute janus:

https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway (readme.md file)

> [FATAL] [janus.c:main:3670] No Janus API transport is available...
>   enable at least one and restart Janus

Anyone has any idea what the issue might be? I will only use the REST API without WebStockets or RabbitMQ.

Answer (score 8):

I successfully installed Janus on Ubuntu 14 according to the following steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libmicrohttpd-dev libjansson-dev libnice-dev libssl-dev libsrtp-dev libsofia-sip-ua-dev libglib2.0-dev libopus-dev libogg-dev libini-config-dev libcollection-dev libwebsockets-dev pkg-config gengetopt automake libtool doxygen graphviz git cmake

sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev

mkdir -p ~/build
cd ~/build
git clone git://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway.git
cd janus-gateway
sh autogen.sh
./configure --disable-data-channels --disable-websockets --disable-rabbitmq --disable-docs --prefix=/opt/janus LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include"

make && sudo make install
sudo make configs
```

Running it by:

```
cd /opt/janus/bin/
./janus -F /opt/janus/etc/janus/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before, I had write a script to install everything just run this

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/johnmelodyme/966f474a99b6dd0cf4e7ac19ba4258da/raw/0f1779499c62eeee3e2a577ef641e94e57b71154/janus.sh && sh janus.sh
```

Hope This Help Much, I believe there are certain dependencies needs to be installation but you missed it. In https://github.com/meetecho/janus-gateway it stated the Dependencies needed, have to be installed without error.

Answer (score 0):

It is because libmicrohttpd version is lower than requirement, Download and install libmicrohttpd manually (dont use yum or apt-get).